# what is the right way of mounting an ext4 formatted ssd or nvm?

Tags: mount, ext4, ssd, automounting, nvme

I have mounted 2 external disks like this shown below (in fstab)

```
UUID=e3831bf2-d85d-459f-8091-4af1d3c6ee41        /mnt/ssd ext4   defaults        0       1
UUID=38cebf19-8cea-40ce-9014-d6f2f9d884ac        /fulldisk ext4  defaults        0       1
```

the first one is ssd which does never gives issue but the second one is nvme which for some reason lands in this error:

```
:/fulldisk$ ll
ls: reading directory '.': Input/output error
total 0
```

then I have to shutdown computer and wait for a while a turn it on and its good to go.

Comment: If I understand correctly, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn’t. The first thing to do is physically remove the nvme drive and then refit it. There is a fair chance this is a poor electrical connection

Comment: If NVMe drive but external, it really is a USB drive and you are using a NVMe/USB adapter. Some adapters are better than others. And For USB connected stuff, use autofs, always. use /misc/<LABEL> typically & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1047109/how-can-i-delay-mount-of-secondary-internal-hard-drive-on-boot?noredirect=1#comment1710066_1047109
use noauto if mount issues

Comment: taking what little you described at face value, it gives the impression there is a disk error causing your input/out error, because your fstab syntax is all you should need to do and if `mount` gives no warning and no error then not sure what else would cause that on the linux side.  Consider using `smartctl` to scan the problem disk to diagnose.  Based on what you said I don't think the disk being nvme as anything to do with it.... especially if it periodically works after waiting a while.